# SQL - Can I calculate a new column based on another new one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a query in which there is a new column calculated similar to the following:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND
turnover >= 3000 THEN '500'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND
turnover < 3000 THEN '200'
ELSE '0' END as OfferAmountEuro,
```

This works fine. I now want to create another calculated field on the same table which uses the 'OfferAmountEuro' field in it's calculation. I tried something like this:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND
turnover >= 3000 THEN '500'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND
turnover < 3000 THEN '200'
ELSE '0' END as OfferAmountEuro,
CASE WHEN OfferAmountEuro = 500 AND Currency ='USD' then '600'
WHEN OfferAmountEuro = 200 AND Currency ='USD' then '250'
ELSE '0' END as OfferAmountLocal
```

But I get an error stating that 'OfferAmountEuro' is an invalid column name. I assume this means that I can't use the newly calculated 'OfferAmountEuro' field in the calculation for 'OfferAmountLocal'?

The actual calculations for the 'OfferAmountEuro' field are much more complex and numerous than the above in reality and I'd rather not repeat each of these calcs for the 'OfferAmountLocal' field.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a quick way to use this 'OfferAmountEuro' field in the calcs for another new field?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server they are different databases, yet you've tagged this with both?

Answer (score 1):

Your column is not recognized, because of natural sql statement execution order. Read more here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries

If you're using SQL Server, you can use CROSS APPLY as a workaround.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN D.OfferAmountEuro = 500 AND T.Currency ='USD' then '600'
        WHEN D.OfferAmountEuro = 200 AND T.Currency ='USD' then '250'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS OfferAmountLocal
FROM YourTable AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T.LastPurchase, GETDATE()) < 31 AND T.TurnOver >= 3000 THEN '500'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T.LastPurchase, GETDATE()) < 31 AND T.TurnOver < 3000 THEN '200'
            ELSE '0'
        END
    ) AS D(OfferAmountEuro)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the original query in a WITH statement and reference it in a second query, or replace all of the logic in your first computed column anywhere you want to use it.

Something like:

```
WITH C1 AS (
    SELECT *, 
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND turnover >= 3000 THEN '500'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,lastpurchase,getdate())< 31 AND turnover < 3000 THEN '200'
        ELSE '0' END as OfferAmountEuro
    FROM myTable
    )
SELECT *, 
   CASE WHEN OfferAmountEuro = 500 AND Currency ='USD' then '600'
        WHEN OfferAmountEuro = 200 AND Currency ='USD' then '250'
        ELSE '0' END as OfferAmountLocal
FROM C1
```